# ContentDialog from XAML in UAP

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I need to show ContentDialog that is not attached to any page.

Currently I construct it dynamically in the code.

How can I define it in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `UserControl` item to your project and changing its base type to `ContentDialog` with the following Body:

```
<ContentDialog .../>
-or-
<ContentDialog>
    singleObject
</ContentDialog>
-or-
<ContentDialog>stringContent</ContentDialog>
```

See [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)